# How to deal with Windows’ sleep and hibernate issues?

Tags: windows, update, drivers, laptop, hibernate

Windows’ sleep and hibernate seem to cause problems since forever. After resuming, drivers crash even on some of the latest ThinkPads (typically the ones with discrete graphics). Previously, we have had instances of laptops that refused to wake up.

Disabling both sleep and hibernate is a way out but obviously allow the laptops to drain their batteries when idle, which is not so great.

Driver updates (if available) often fix it, but we have seen resume from sleep/hibernate issues across many models and different brands a countless of times over the years.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: Migrate to Apple machines. ;)

Comment: Migrating to [paper](http://www.creatifulkids.com/paper-computer/) would also solve all [Apple related](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/240728-apples-new-macbook-pro-touch-bar-massive-battery-life-problems) [power management](http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/24/when-and-how-to-reset-your-mac-system-management-controller-smc/) [issues](https://www.cnet.com/news/managing-problems-with-apples-macbook-power-adapters/). @EEAA

Comment: @EsaJokinen I think you missed my wink.

Comment: @EEAA That is just great, mate. I actually made that suggestion in a jokingly manner earlier. It is quite unlikely that will ever happen though.

Comment: @EEAA: I did notice it - didn't just add one to my own as I consider the sarcasm as extremely transparent. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem on Apple devices, as well as Linux and Windows machines on x86 hardware. It's typically a combination of hardware, firmware, and driver problems. It's what we get for pushing forward new standards (and sometimes weird ACPI hacks within firmware to deal with strange problems that arise in new models).

There isn't a huge amount you can typically do to fix it beyond keeping your firmware and drivers updated (unless the driver you're dealing with is open source). This is especially the case with discrete graphics devices, since their firmware is sometimes mildly incompatible with a given custom ACPI implementation, for example (this isn't usually a problem on desktops). So keep it all updated, and don't forget about firmware.

Be careful about what you buy. There are some laptops, tablets, and chipsets that are notorious failures in this arena. When considering a purchase, it's not a bad idea to look up this kind of problem as it relates to a machine, GPU, or chipset model. There are a lot of sites for this, so Google is the best tool here.